# request Json transformation using xslt

Tags: xslt

```
    <html>    
Hi,
I have a sample json in this format:

{
  "d": {
    "results": [      
      {        
        "TYPE_ID": "20",
        "QUESTION_ID": "41333",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE": "Checkboxes",
        "QUESTIONVAL": "xssdsdd",
        "RESPONSE": "Yes",
        "RESPONSE_ORDER": "1"        
      }, 
      {        
        "TYPE_ID": "21",
        "QUESTION_ID": "417",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE": "Radio buttons",
        "QUESTIONVAL": "abc",
        "RESPONSE": "Yes,No",
        "RESPONSE_ORDER": "1,2"       
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to extract the comma separated values from the RESPONSEs and  RESPONSE_ORDER tag, such that I can distinctly set them in my output JSON.
    Essentially, my output should be some what like this using xslt transformation.

```
{
    "results": [      
      {        
        "TYPE_ID": "20",
        "QUESTION_ID": "41333",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE": "Checkboxes",
        "QUESTIONVAL": "xssdsdd",
        Response&Order: [
            {
            "RESPONSE": "Yes",
            "RESPONSE_ORDER": "1"
            }
        ]               
      }, 
      {        
        "TYPE_ID": "21",
        "QUESTION_ID": "417",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE": "Radio buttons",
        "QUESTIONVAL": "abc",
        Response&Order: [
            {
            "RESPONSE": "Yes",
            "RESPONSE_ORDER": "1"
            },
            {
            "RESPONSE": "No",
            "RESPONSE_ORDER": "2"
            }
        ]             
      }
    ]
}

How can I split the values to generate this kind of output?

   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

XSLT doesn't support JSON until version 3.0. There's some support in Saxon 9.6 (PE edition and higher). Essentially you have to convert the JSON to XML, transform it, and then convert back again. (In theory XSLT 3.0 allows you to transform JSON directly, but in my experience it's much easier to do it via XML. That's mainly, I think, because the data model for XML allows you to navigate to siblings and ancestors, and the data model for JSON doesn't. This is illustrated in my solution below.

The following stylesheet does the job in Saxon 9.6:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:j="http://www.w3.org/2013/XSL/json"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:variable name="input" expand-text="no">
        {"d": {"results": [
        {
        "TYPE_ID": "20",
        "QUESTION_ID": "41333",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE": "Checkboxes",
        "QUESTIONVAL": "xssdsdd",
        "RESPONSE": "Yes",
        "RESPONSE_ORDER": "1"
        },
        {
        "TYPE_ID": "21",
        "QUESTION_ID": "417",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE": "Radio buttons",
        "QUESTIONVAL": "abc",
        "RESPONSE": "Yes,No",
        "RESPONSE_ORDER": "1,2"
        }
        ]}}
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:variable name="inputAsXml" select="json-to-xml($input)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="outputAsXml">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$inputAsXml"/>          
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($outputAsXml, map{'indent':true()})"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@key='d']">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@key='RESPONSE_ORDER']"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[@key='RESPONSE']">
            <xsl:variable name="response" select="tokenize(., ',')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="responseOrder" select="tokenize(../*[@key='RESPONSE_ORDER'], ',')"/>
            <j:array key="Response&amp;Order">
                <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($response)">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="."/>
                    <j:map>
                       <j:string key="RESPONSE">{$response[$i]}</j:string>
                       <j:string key="RESPONSE_ORDER">{$responseOrder[$i]}</j:string>
                    </j:map> 
                </xsl:for-each>
            </j:array>       
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output produced is:

```
  { "results" : 
    [ 
      { "TYPE_ID" : "20",
        "QUESTION_ID" : "41333",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE" : "Checkboxes",
        "QUESTIONVAL" : "xssdsdd",
        "Response&Order" : 
        [ 
          { "RESPONSE" : "Yes",
            "RESPONSE_ORDER" : "1" } ] },

      { "TYPE_ID" : "21",
        "QUESTION_ID" : "417",
        "RESPONSE_TYPE" : "Radio buttons",
        "QUESTIONVAL" : "abc",
        "Response&Order" : 
        [ 
          { "RESPONSE" : "Yes",
            "RESPONSE_ORDER" : "1" },

          { "RESPONSE" : "No",
            "RESPONSE_ORDER" : "2" } ] } ] }
```

The main XSLT 3.0 features used here are the two functions json-to-xml() and xml-to-json(). To understand the transformation you will need to understand the XML representation of JSON used by these functions, which is explained here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json-to-xml-mapping

The XSLT 3.0 specification is still a draft, and there may be changes before final publication. The only change needed to get this working against the current (unpublished) working draft is a change of namespace; instead of http://www.w3.org/2013/XSL/json, use http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your help on this  requirement. As per your comment i can proceed further. Also there is some article, where XSLT can be used for transforming JSON. So just want to confirm on this?

Comment: No, you won't find any body of literature on this. You're on the bleeding edge.

Comment: Basically I'm working on API , which will get response from a back-end service and applying the transformation on it. I have no option to read complete response and convert it to XML and do transformation and convert it back to JSON response. I did a simple transformation for remove __metadata tag from the json response like can u suggest how to do it xslt for this scenario.

Comment: This is the sample XSLT:

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" ....>
<xsl:param name="url_prefix"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="__metadata">
        <xsl:variable name="extractVal2" select=
                'substring-before(substring-after(uri, "&#40;"), "&#41;")'/>
        <uri>
            <xsl:value-of select="$url_prefix"/>/<xsl:value-of select="$extractVal2"/>
        </uri>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: As above example If you can suggest xslt transformation for this requirement. Appreciate it.

Comment: This looks like a completely unrelated question. Please accept my answer if it solves your original question, and then raise a new question starting from scratch.